# Unit testing a nested method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Say I have a service like so:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoStuff(IDependency dependency, string value)
    {
        dependency.SomeMethod(value, true);
        DoOtherStuff(dependency);
    }

    public void DoOtherStuff(IDependency dependency)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Now, when unit testing `MyService`, I can mock the dependency easily enough and test the dependency is properly used:

```
public void MyServiceTest()
{
    // Arrange 
    var mockDependency = new Mock<IDependency>();
    mockDependency.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod());
    var service = new MyService();

    // Act
    service.DoStuff(mockDependency.Object, "value");

    // Assert
    mockDependency.Verify(v => v.SomeMethod(), Times.Once);
}
```

How do I test that the service calls `DoOtherStuff`?  Or is this a bad pattern?  What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not care for unit test how particular public functionality is implemented as long as it satisfies its contract.

Note: "public" above used in general sense of "externally usable", usually it aligns with C# `public`, but sometimes you want/have to mark additional methods as public even if it really not part of external contract.

If you really must test that `DoOtherStuff` is called you can make that method `virtual` and use test implementation that provides its own version that somehow notifies you about the call (possibly Moq can build one for you too).

Answer (score 2):

For another class you'd use moq, as written.

However, the class is under test and I think you shouldn't separate out the two methods in your testing, for similar reasons that you don't test private methods. When it comes down to it if the code is refactored such that your second method isn't called should tests fail. No, the public API is unaffected.

Better to make assertions about what should happen to dependency as DoOtherStuff is called, as you are doing now.

Comment: As a note (deliberately not putting in answer body), if the methods were virtual you could override them in your test. I don't see this being a very helpful thing to do in most circumstances, however. I think the heart of why we care that something gets called Times.Once is because it's an interaction between classes. Also  `Delegate.CreateDelegate(Metadata<Func<DynamicMethod, RuntimeMethodHandle>> etc etc`. There is also the way of the dark side, but I'm not intimately familiar.